# Why can't I see all the objects within this blender project?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

I have downloaded [this (excellent) rendering of a terrarium](https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/forest-in-a-jar-terrarium-4dca1b2513394d0fa0ed12041ff30ddc), but when I examine it in Blender, it appears to only have a single object - the glass jar, and none of the other vertices are visible, even in edit mode.

[image]

As soon as I go out of edit mode, I can see more vertices, but I can't select them or modify them:

[image]

I'm sure this is obvious, but I don't know what to google for to resolve it. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So I guess you've tried Alt H in Edit mode? Maybe share the file (if it's authorized of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the content of the jar is the same object, but the vertices are hidden in *Edit Mode*. Go to *Edit Mode* and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to unhide everything.

Tip: by default, the revealed vertices will be selected. So if you want to separate the jar and the content, when in *Edit Mode* first deselect everything with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then reveal the hidden vertices with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and while they are selected and the jar is not, press <kbd>P</kbd> > *Separate* > *Selection*.

Comment: Ah what an idiot! Massively helpful, thank you!